# pass current web credentials from asp.net web application to a windows client application in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-applications, authentication

I'm developing a web application that requires the user to log in using forms authentication. inside the webpage you need to download a desktop application that requires to login to the same system too. Is there a way to transfer the current logged credentials from the web application to the windows desktop application without need to login again?. Both applications shares a Login object from an vb.net interface.

I tried to save the IP address in the Database but that don't work for me because the website needs to be accessed inside and/or outside of the company and the user cannot login twice in different machines.

I tried to google for solutions but without luck.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be *exactly* the scenario you're envisioning, but this article shows how to use Forms authentication from a Winforms client using WCF Authentication Services.  This should get you going in the right direction.  Per the article, you can use these services in any .NET application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx

This article shows how to do it with a Silverlight app, just so you have another example.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/05/03/accessing-the-asp-net-authentication-profile-and-role-service-in-silverlight.aspx

And just one more for fun.  http://aspalliance.com/1595_Client_Application_Services__Part_1.all#Page1

Comment: Hi David. Thenks for the information. This sounds interesting. Let me check on it and I'll let you know any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. You gave me an idea of how to do this authentication model. Regards

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any way to share this without encrypting a file containing the user's credentials and storing it on the hard drive along with the file, but then you run the risk of someone decrypting the information and getting access to the user's password.

I think that an alternate approach that could work is to generate an authentication token (could be as simple as a GUID) and store it in your database along with the user's id when the user requests the download. You would want this token to expire after a reasonable time limit (5 minutes, for example).

You could then include a file that contains this authentication token with the download. When your apps starts, you could check for the existence of the file. If it's there, you extract the token, delete the file, send the token prior to presenting the user login.

If the token valid, your server would send back the user's login and your app would proceed as though the user were logged in, otherwise you would just display the login screen.

Comment: Good morning competent_tech. I appreciate your response. How can I force the user to download the file since the application is expected to download as a clickonce installer?. Regards

Comment: The way that we do something similar is to build a self-extracting zip file and on extract, place the key file in a well-known location (i.e. userdata), then launch the extracted installer. This may not, however, work with a clickonce installer (we abandoned clickonce awhile ago in favor of a self-built implementation that gives us a lot more flexibility and control).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Using the information displayed above and your information gaves me an idea of how to implement this authentication scheme. Regards